# Retrieve array from string with regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex, arrays

I have following string:
`"option1,option2->data1,data2,data3,..."`

I'm learning C# and also regular expressions, so I thought I might have some fun with it, but I can't figure out how to get an array from this.

For example, I'd like to retrieve array of strings that looks like this one:
`[option1,option2,data1,data2,data3,...]`

Here's regular expression I wrote in regex tester `(.+),(.+)->((.+),?)`, but I'm not sure if this will work. And also I don't know how to use regex functions in C# to achieve this. I guess I should use something from `System.Text.RegularExpressions` but I'm not really sure what.

**Long story short:**
I want to get array from string using regular expressions.

`"option1,option2->data1,data2,..."` -> `[option1,option2,data1,data2,...]`

Thanks!

Comment: A quick Google search should turn up many examples of using regular expressions in C#.  [Here's one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I really like those "quick google search" comments. I'm not native english speaker, and sometimes google doesn't spit out answers I'm looking for. Anyway, thansk for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid RegularExpressions for this. you can simply do this:

```
string[] myArray = inputString.Replace("->", ",").Split(',');
```

Comment: `','` instead of `","` though

Comment: Great idea, thanks. But is there an easy way to use regular expressions?

Comment: The point of my example was practice, not choosing the best approach but what ever.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you need direction more than an answer.

http://www.RegexHero.com is a good place to test your regex against strings.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet is a cheat sheet/guide for c# regex

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match here's a good place to start with regex in c#

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posed anything that `string.Split` can't handle:

```
var split = given.Split(new [] {",", "->"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```